# how to fetch enitre column values in sfmc/email from data extension. Using ampscript

Tags: javascript, ampscript

how to fetch enitre column values in sfmc/email from data extension. Using ampscript?

eg.
countries -> column name
Australia
Singapore
Malaysian
newZealand
africa

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must do something like this:

@country variable will have each value of your countries column.

```
set @dataRow = LookupRows("YOUR_DE", "some_column_from_de", "equalsTo")
set @rowCount = RowCount(@dataRow)

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
    set @row = row(@dataRow, @i)
    set @country = row(@row, "countries")
next
```